# Getting Error while running SONAR Analysis Report

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am using *sonar.java.source=1.5* in my sonar configuration file, so that I can run report for Java Version 1.5.

I am using sonarqube 4.0. 
Downloaded, JavaEcosystem-1.5.zip , to get sonar-pmd-plugin-1.5.
I tried to put sonar-pmd-plugin-1.5 in the folder C:\sonarqube-4.0\web\deploy\plugins\pmd, but it did not help.

I think, I am doing something wrong here. Any pointers?

My sonar-project.properties, looks like below:

```
    # required metadata
sonar.projectKey=<poject key>
sonar.projectName=<project name>
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=<Description>

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src/main/java

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=java
# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Additional parameters
#sonar.my.property=value
```

I am getting following error:

```
19:45:59.428 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3...
19:45:59.436 INFO  - Execute PMD 4.3 done: 8 ms
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8.104s
Final Memory: 8M/101M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 1.5
ERROR: Caused by: Unsupported Java version for PMD: 1.5
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: I've just made the test, and it works correctly. Could you please update your question to add more details about your configuration: are you using Maven or the SonarRunner? What is the content of your config file?... And BTW, the sonar-pmd-plugin -1.5.jar file must be (like any other plugins) in "/extensions/plugins" only (do not modify the content of the webapp please).

Comment: I am using the local SonarRunner (2.3 version), C:\sonarqube-4.0\extensions\plugins, I see the JAR with suffix 1.4, not 1.5. I will update the question with sonar-project.properties.